# Drawing all diagonals of a regular polygon

Tags: graph-theory

I can draw all the diagonals of a pentagon and heptagon without lifting my pen. But I am not able do so with a hexagon. Is it possible? I think it has something to do with prime numbers. 
In general which polygons obey the the above property?

Comment: Can you do it for a square?

Comment: I know it is not possible.

Comment: I assume it is not allowed to draw along the sides of the polygon?

Comment: Then maybe it has something to do with even/odd number of sides?

Comment: No, I am not allowed to draw along sides of polygon.

Comment: You seem to impose a further condition that a diagonal cannot be traced more than once, something that "without lifting my pen" does not clearly require.  If retracing is allowed, then of course it is possible to draw the diagonals of a hexagon "without lifting my pen".

Comment: A famous puzzle "The Seven Bridges of Königsberg" can be solved with the same sort of analysis that this problem requires. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg

Answer (score 8):

Prime numbers aren't involved; **odd** numbers are. In a regular $n$-gon, each vertex is the endpoint of $n-3$ diagonals, and it is well-known that a graph is Eulerian (can be drawn in one stroke) if and only if all its vertices' degrees are even. So here we require $n-3$ to be even, and this is only true if $n$ is odd.

Hence you can draw the diagonals of the pentagon, heptagon, nonagon and so on in one stroke. You cannot do this for the square, hexagon, octagon and so on.

The result remains unchanged if we also draw the polygon itself (to get what is sometimes called a mystic rose); replace the $n-3$ above with $n-1$, and you get the same result.

Comment: can the drawing end on a vertice from where I did not start the graph?

Comment: @jnyan Guess what. With the diagonals of an odd-sided polygon, no matter how you go along the edges, _you must end up where you started_, because all the vertices have even degree.

Comment: No.  In a graph where every vertex has an even number of edges, a path that covers all the edges must return to the starting point. This is becasue when you start there are an odd number of edges left at that vertex.  Every other vertex has an even number of edges, so when you come in there is an edge to leave on.  You can have a graph with two vertices with an odd number of edges, like a square with one diagonal drawn.  You can cover all the edges, but must start at one odd vertex and end at the other.

Comment: but I guess i cannot go in any direction I desire. Sometimes I cant complete the graph. is that right?

Comment: Yes. There is an algorithm that (given an Eulerian graph) constructs an explicit Eulerian cycle in it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: can you do that for $n=3,5,7...$? What about $n=4,6,8...$?